# How to get a variable into an element name in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

Sorry, I just can't get my head around this:

Is there a way to turn this...

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat('name-', $language)" />
```

...into this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="name-en" />
```

?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Did you want to output the literal string 'name-en'? or the value of the element whose name is <name-en>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<xsl:value-of select='*[name() = concat("name-", $language)]' />
```

**[Live demo](http://www.xmlplayground.com/0Q4L2x)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <xsl:variable name="name-en" select="concat('name-', $language)">
 </xsl:variable>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you actually meant to achieve the equivalent of...

```
<xsl:value-of select="'name-en'" />
```

(Note the quote marks around 'name-en'.) If this was not your intention, then please let me know.

**Just set the value of the $language variable to 'en'**, like so ...

```
<xsl:variable name="language" select="'en'" />
```

Incidently, if you are using XSLT 2.0 , rather than 1.0, you can abbreviate ...

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat('name-', $language)" />
```

... into ....

```
<xsl:value-of select="'name-', $language" />
```

Nice one!

Answer (score 0):

**Just judging by the title**:

> How to get a variable into an element name in XSLT?

**The answer is**:

```
<xsl:element name="{$theVariable}"/>
```

This generates an element whose name is the value of the `$theVariable` variable.

**In your specific case use**:

```
<xsl:element name="name-{$language}"/>
```

**Explanation**:

Proper use of **[`<xsl:element>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#section-Creating-Elements-with-xsl%3aelement)** and **[AVT](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#attribute-value-templates)** (Attribute Value Templates).

Comment: But I suspect that the element name required is an element in the input, not one in the output.

Comment: @MichaelKay: The title says: ...get a variable *into* an element name.

Comment: @Tintin81: If so, please edit the question and explain well, so that people will not have to guess -- also remember this when writing new questions.